# Abort installation when dependency fails to install

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I have one .msi file and two prerequisites files. As per my code, the setup will execute main exe file from .msi file after successful installation. But if the previous version of .msi file is already installed, it coming with the option of **Repair and Remove**. My `Run` section is running after I uninstalled .msi file and I want to quit the application after it removed msi file or it will not execute the `Run` section. Can anyone please suggest me some solutions?

Here is my `Run` section:

```
[Run]
Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; \
    Parameters: "/verysilent /group=""{groupname}\Macrowire 2.5 Pro"" /mergetasks=""desktopicon,file_association"""; \
    Flags: nowait postinstall; \
    Description: "{cm:LaunchProgram,{#StringChange(MyAppName, '&', '&&')}}"; \
    StatusMsg: "Installing Macrowire 2.5 Pro..."
```

Here is my Pascal code:

```pascal
function PrepareToInstall(var NeedsRestart: Boolean): String;
var 
  ResultCode: integer;
begin
  ...
  if IsComponentSelected('Macrowire') or IsComponentSelected('Full') then
  begin
    ShellExec('', ExpandConstant('{app}\MacroWire 2.5 Pro.msi'), '', '', SW_SHOW,
      ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode) 
  end;
  ...
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to abort the installation when the dependency fails to install:

```pascal
function PrepareToInstall(var NeedsRestart: Boolean): String;
var 
  ResultCode: integer;
begin
  ...
  if IsComponentSelected('Macrowire') or IsComponentSelected('Full') then
  begin
    { Using Exec, the ShellExec is an overkill }
    Exec(ExpandConstant('{app}\MacroWire 2.5 Pro.msi'), '', '', SW_SHOW,
         ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode);
    // Here we are testing the existence of the installed binary.
    // A more generic solution would be to test result code of the installer:
    // if ResultCode <> 0 then
    if not FileExists(ExpandConstant('{app}\{#MyAppExeName}')) then
    begin
      Result := 'Failed to install MacroWire';
      Exit;
    end;
  end;
  ...
end;
```

---

If you want the installation to continue, but you just need to skip the `[Run]` entry, use the [`Check` parameter](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptcheck):

```
[Run]
Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Parameters: "..."; Flags: nowait postinstall; \
    Description: "..."; Check: FileExists(ExpandConstant('{app}\{#MyAppExeName}'))
```

---

Btw, the `StatusMsg` parameter is not used with `postinstall` entries. And I'm still not sure if the installer-like `Parameters` are relevant for this program.