# Installing R automatically with Inno Setup

Tags: python, r, inno-setup

I am creating a setup from python program (compiled with pyinstaller) successfully with Inno Setup. However, I call R functions with rpy2 in my program. Therefore I want the setup procedure check whether the user has installed R. If not, it can install R automatically. I found there are similar answers of .Net (https://engy.us/blog/2015/07/17/installing-net-framework-4-5-automatically-with-inno-setup/), but I do not know how to do with R.

Comment: Just run the R installer from the Inno Setup-made installer? The same way as any other dependency, like .NET here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/20752882/850848

Comment: Yes, but if it can be better for checking that only after successful installation of R, will the installation of my app continue.

Comment: See [Abort installation when dependency fails to install](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37131619/850848).